# Kubernetes sample micro services based application (containers talk through REST API)

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for a simple application to be deployed on Kubernetes environment, that is divided to docker micro services, that some of the microservices talk to each other with REST API.

Somebody?

I'll be happy to get full details of how to install it on my environment (I have 3 hosts VMs)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only care about the application usage in Kubernetes or do you also want to setup a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of application examples in the kubernetes [github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/e3fa83177c4d2d1331d41e7ce70b1f145475587a/examples). The [Guestbook application](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/e3fa83177c4d2d1331d41e7ce70b1f145475587a/examples/guestbook#guestbook-example) will be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Udacity has a free course about "Scalable microservice with Kubernetes"
https://www.udacity.com/course/scalable-microservices-with-kubernetes--ud615

It is a real good starting point.